# MediaCtrl class raises NotImplementedError exception (wxpython)

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

when i running this code in my raspberry carde:

```
try:
        self.mc = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self.conteneur,pos=(10,10))
except NotImplementedError:
        self.Destroy()
        raise
```

i show a message like:media.mediaCtrl(*args,**kwargs) NotImplementdError.
i want to know if ican resolve this problem.

can any one help me to know why the mediaCtrl cannot be displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that when wxWidgets was built either the building of the media ctrl classes was turned off, or some dependency was not found so it was turned off automatically.  If you built wxWidgets and wxPython yourself then try again and watch the output of the wxWidgets configure step for clues as to what it is missing.  Otherwise check with whoever built the packages you installed.